# Using Windows Server, how do I schedule an hourly task that will call a URL WITH an authorization header?

Tags: windows-server-2008, scheduled-task, authorization

I need to schedule a task that will call a given url hourly.  The URL doesn't return anything so it is fairly simple HOWEVER this URL requires an authorization header:

`Authorization: Basic {SOME AUTH CODE}`

How do I append this header to the request with Windows Task Scheduler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**cURL**](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) in a script and set it to be run via scheduled task.

You don't have to set the authorization header manually, you can just use the `--user` argument

```
curl --user user:pass http://www.example.com
```

If you really want to add the header manually use the `-H / --header` switch.  More on that [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356705/how-to-send-a-header-using-a-http-request-through-a-curl-call).

```
curl -H "Authorization: [auth string]" http://www.example.com
```